# Regex unexpected behavior with capturing new lines (python)

Tags: regex, python-re

I'm trying to find lines in large amount of text with 4 words or less and ending with ":". The text is messed up so any whitespace can show up at the beginning or end of the line (and I don't want that to affect my code).
Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
import re
my_string="""Requirements:
Knowledge Required:"""
pattern = r'^\s*(?:\S+\s+){0,3}\S*:\s*$'
print(re.findall(pattern, my_string, flags=re.MULTILINE))
```

Expected output would be:

```
['Requirements:', 'Knowledge Required']
```

Instead, I get:

```
['Requirements:\nKnowledge Required']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```bash
^\s*(?:\S+\s+){0,3}\S*:\s*$
```

Here, problem is that `\s` also matches line breaks not just horizontal whitespaces. You can instead use this:

```bash
^[ \t]*(?:\S+[ \t]+){0,3}\S*:[ \t]*$
```

Where `[ \t]` will match a space or a tab character.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that `\S` will match `:`, and `\s` will match newline. So `(?:\S+\s+){0,3}\S*:` will match `Requirements:\nKnowledge Required`. See [this demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/V4BQop/1). You need to exclude `:` from words and newline from whitespace (you can probably simply use   (space)) i.e.

```
^ *(?:[^:\s]+ +){0,3}[^: ]*: *$
```

In python:

```
my_string="""Requirements:
Knowledge Required:"""
pattern = r'^ *(?:[^:\s]+ +){0,3}[^: ]*: *$'
print(re.findall(pattern, my_string, flags=re.MULTILINE))
```

Output:

```
['Requirements:', 'Knowledge Required:']
```